# Why Mockito.verify() don't work with jpa.domain.Specifications?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I have the method for selecting by filter through `springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications` in the Service layer and I trying test it:

```
@Override
public Page<Phone> list(@NonNull final PhoneFilter filter) {
    Specification<Phone> specs = new PhoneSpecification(filter);
    return phoneRepository.findAll(where(specs), filter.getPageable());
}
```

But my test don't work:

```
@Test
public void whenCallListWithEmptyFilterThenRepoIsCalledFindAll() {
    PhoneFilter filter = new PhoneFilter(new PageRequest(0 , 1));
    phoneService.list(filter);
    PhoneSpecification spec = new PhoneSpecification(filter);
    verify(phoneRepository).findAll(where(spec), filter.getPageable());
}
```

Starace talks about the different arguments, but I still can't figure it out what the different.

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
phoneRepository bean.findAll(
    org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications@47d533c0,
    Page request [number: 0, size 1, sort: null]
);
-> at ru.pravvich.service.PhoneServiceImplTest.whenCallListWithEmptyFilterThenRepoIsCalledFindAll(PhoneServiceImplTest.java:80)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
phoneRepository bean.findAll(
    org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications@12129ef3,
    Page request [number: 0, size 1, sort: null]
);
-> at ru.pravvich.service.PhoneServiceImpl.list(PhoneServiceImpl.java:35)

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
phoneRepository bean.findAll(
    org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications@47d533c0,
    Page request [number: 0, size 1, sort: null]
);
-> at ru.pravvich.service.PhoneServiceImplTest.whenCallListWithEmptyFilterThenRepoIsCalledFindAll(PhoneServiceImplTest.java:80)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
phoneRepository bean.findAll(
    org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications@12129ef3,
    Page request [number: 0, size 1, sort: null]
);
-> at ru.pravvich.service.PhoneServiceImpl.list(PhoneServiceImpl.java:35)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at ru.pravvich.service.PhoneServiceImplTest.whenCallListWithEmptyFilterThenRepoIsCalledFindAll(PhoneServiceImplTest.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The `Specifications` object is equaled and this is should be enough I think. But instance is different: `Specifications@47d533c0` and `Specifications@12129ef3` I think this is doesn't important.

Why my test doesn't work? And how to fix it?

If you have the version why it's happening or needs more information about details this case, let me know. Thank You!

**EDIT 1**

PhoneSpecification class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
class PhoneSpecification implements Specification<Phone> {

    private final @NonNull PhoneFilter filter;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Phone> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
        if (nonNull(filter.id)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), filter.id));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.note)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("note"), toLike(filter.note, ANY)));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.number)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("number"), toLike(filter.number, ANY)));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.status)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("status"), toLike(filter.status, ANY)));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.opName)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("operatorName"), toLike(filter.opName, ANY)));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.login)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("operatorAccLogin"), toLike(filter.login, ANY)));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.password)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.like(root.get("operatorAccPassword"), toLike(filter.password, ANY)));
        }
        if (nonNull(filter.from) && nonNull(filter.to)) {
            predicate.getExpressions().add(cb.between(root.get("regDate"), filter.from, filter.to));
        }
        return predicate;
    }
}
```

And filter:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
class PhoneFilter {

    private @NonNull Pageable pageable;

    private Integer id;

    private Timestamp from;

    private Timestamp to;

    private String number;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String opName;

    private String status;

    private String note;

}
```

Comment: Does PhoneSpecification implement a correct equals? Because otherwise, Mockito will only know that you have PhoneSpecifications that are not the same and thus fail there. Equals allows it to see that it's the one you actually meant.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz I use lombok implementation `@EqualsAndHashCode` update question.

Comment: Any solutions yet?